# Как я могу вызвать slurm sbatch в отдельном процессе?

Tags: python-3.x, django, subprocess

Мне нужно запустить другую программу с параметрами, основанными на данных формы. У меня есть обработчик страниц на Django. Он строит файл .sh из формы, этот файл вызывается в отдельном процессе с помощью Popen и sbatch. Все это работает нормально, но сама страница зависает, и переполнение памяти происходит через процесс python3. Ниже приведен пример программы:

```
def sbatch_subproc(self, file_path):
  >> Создаётся .sh файл.
  pop_sbatch = subprocess.Popen(args = ["sbatch", sh_file_path])
  >> Что-то должно происходить дальше

def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
  >>Создаётся путь до .sh файла - sh_file_path.
  proc = Process(target = self.sbatch_subproc, args=(sh_file_path))
  proc.start()
```

Пример .sh файла:

```
#!/bin/sh
srun ./program -param1 value1 -param2 value2 -param3 value3
exit 0
```

[image: введит описание изображения]

Пример перегрузки процесса

Comment: может утечка ресурсов какая-то -- `with Popen(`

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov как это можно проверить и устранить? проблема в том, то сама программа выполняется ожидаемо и выдаёт нужные результаты, но потом происходит переполнение памяти

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov проблема оказывается была не в самом процессе, а в другой части когда, который и создавал переполнение памяти. Спасибо